# Assigning a public IP to a Xen Guest machine

Tags: xen, linux-networking

On my CentOS server (dom0) I have 4 Ip addresses:

- eth1 - 56.x.x.100
- eth1:1 - 56.x.x.101
- eth1:2 - 56.x.x.102
- eth1:3 - 56.x.x.103

How can I map eth1:1 (etc) to one of my guest machine? Currently the Guest machine have NATed private IP address using the bridge interface virbr0 (ip: 192.168.122.192). What to do to have the guest machine use 56.x.x.101 ip address instead of 192.168.122.192?

I'm new to Linux networking, and I have spent time around on the internet looking for solutions for long time already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to remove eth1:1 from your host.

You then need to create a bridge on the CentOS host -- there are many guides for how to do this. A bridge will act as a virtual network switch (for the purposes of this explanation). Instead of joining your VM to `virbr0`, you join it to `xenbr0` (or whatever you bridge gets named). This will make your VM virtually connected to the same switch as your host, allowing you to assign the .101 address to `eth0` *inside* the guest VM.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to create another bridge and join it to the existing one? tq

Comment: No, you need to create another bridge and join it to `eth0` -- do NOT join it to the existing bridge. You will end up with 2 bridges: 1 joined to your actual network where you can use your public addresses, and 1 virtual network that is purely for the VM's to use private addresses (your host NAT's traffic from this second bridge/network)